# How cmake can set different gcc flags for each module?

Tags: gcc, cmake, static-libraries

I want create project c++ (gcc) with submodules - static libraries. Base library should be always build optimized and without debug info, main module can be not optimized and with debug info.
First flag solution is CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:

```
project(example)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -std=c++14")
add_executable(example main.cpp example.cpp log.h example.h)
add_library(log log.cpp log.h)
target_link_libraries(example log)
```

But this solution is global. Better is add_compile_options:

```
project(example)
add_compile_options(-std=c++14)
add_executable(example main.cpp example.cpp log.h example.h)
add_compile_options(-O3)
add_library(log log.cpp log.h)
target_link_libraries(example log)
```

but again - second modules must be flags upset of first module, I can only add options, not change.

Comment: `target_link_libraries(example log)` ==> `target_link_libraries(example PUBLIC log)`

Comment: Also, don't play with `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. Use [`CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html)` instead

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`target_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_options.html) instead of `add_compile_options`.